# SQL Server query: Uncaught TypeError: content is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, sqlcommand

What I am trying to do, is query from my database and populate the columns inside my `Index.cshtml`.

Below is my code:

This is from my `HomeController`:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP;Initial Catalog=SchedulerEvent;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework");

public JsonResult GetEvents()
{
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Event", con);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    var events = command;
    return new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

This is what my database looks like:

[image]

Further inspection shows me the area where it is null

[image]

I console log on my frontend and the image below is what it print:

[image]

This should not be the case since my query is `SELECT * FROM Event` but it is not fetching the content of my table.

But the thing is, as you have seen from my database screenshot, the column `Subject` is not empty or null.

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: Looks like all you're doing is opening the connection, where is the query to actually fetch the events from the database?

Comment: i edited my answer to include the command to query from my database, still having same error

Comment: Have you added a breakpoint to make sure you're sending something back to the view? If so I would use ***debugger;*** before reading from the content to see what values you have and the structure of the data on the client side.

Comment: I updated my answer, the weird thing is i did have a command to fetch all data from the correct table, but it is printing garbage :(

Comment: I even tried  ``` SELECT * FROM dbo.Event``` still have same error

Comment: It’s clearly printing the connection object and not the results of the query. You need to store the results of executing the actual query. See the documentation for SqlCommand.

Comment: You're using `.ExecuteNonQuery()` - but this is intended only for when you do an `UPDATE`, `DELETE` or `INSERT` - any operation that doesn't return a result set. Here, with a `SELECT`, you **want** to get back data as a result set - so you'll need to use `ExecuteReader` (and then iterate over the rows returned) - or use something like Dapper that would handle all the nitty-gritty lowlevel code stuff for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are returning the "command" of type "SqlCommand", this doesnt contain the result/data returned by the query.

you need to implement ExecuteReader()

```
using (SqlDataReader oReader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (oReader.Read())
    {
        // prepare your object to return here.
        Console.WriteLine(oReader["EventId"].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(oReader["Subject"].ToString());
    }
}
```